# Append a parent element to arrays in PHP for a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

`print_r` of `$data = json_decode($src, true);` returns data that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
 [var1] => blah
 [var2] => foo
 ) 
[1] => Array ( 
 [var1] => lorem 
 [var2] => ipsum
 )
  // goes down to [1936]
)
```

I want to build an html table that shows var1 and var2 next to each other in the same row.  I know do to this I need a foreach statement like

`foreach($data['items'] as $item)`

but the problem I think I am having is that my many arrays aren't the child of one thing like `'items'`, right?

I looked into `array_push` but couldn't figure it out.  Can someone help my orphaned parentless arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$data` itself to go through all of the children of `$data`.

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $item["var1"] . "</td><td>" $item["var2"] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Note: Accepted edit, but take note that the brackets are optional. Nice catch on the tags though.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why I assumed I needed a 'parent' to do this.